# Invalid content was found starting with element-PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I am getting below error when I add more than one location to the property.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'value'. No child element is expected at this point.

Which schema is failing with max occurs.? What is the solution for this issue?

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">



<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>constants.properties</value>
        <value>constants2.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Corrected as below after Sotirios Delimanolis's fix.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
     <list>
        <value>constants.properties</value>
        <value>constants2.properties</value>
        <value>file:${pathl}</value>
     </list>            
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any idea why the system cannot find ${pathl} (The system cannot find the file specified). {pathl} is a property of constants2.properties. where the pathl=C\:Temp123.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to change `location` to `locations` which expects an array. Then wrap the `value` elements in a `<array>` element.

You should have

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <array>
            <value>constants.properties</value>
            <value>constants2.properties</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks it is working , any idea why the property <value>file:${pathl}</value> is not loading.What is the solution ?

Comment: @Kasun You need the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to resolve properties. But you're trying to resolve a property for `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, before it's defined.

Comment: so what would be the solution do u recommend ? if I want to load properties from another property file.

Comment: @Kasun Will the location of the properties file change? Just put the value literally.

Comment: location of the file does not get change. But cross platform is the issue. Whenever I make a release to Linux I have to change the path over Windows. Any other solutions in Spring 2.5 branch ?

Comment: @Kasun Not that I can think of right now. However, I think that if you put something like `/temp/path/wtv` in Windows, the path will be resolved against the main drive, ie. where your OS is installed, `C:\temp\path\wtv`. You can use that to your advantage.